# Xamarin forms MVVM Remove the previous VM in my current VM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have a main page : HomeVM.
When the app starts, I use PushModalAsync for RegistrationVM
In my RegistrationVM, I have a button for pushModalAsync -> LoginVM

When the user is connected, I want go back in the VM HomeVM, but impossible, with PopModalAsync, I come back to RegistrationVM.

I would like to close all popmodalasync.

I have tried this

Here in my app.xaml :

```
var mainPage = (Page)ViewFactory.CreatePage(typeof(HomeVM));
MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage)
{
    BarBackgroundColor = (Color)Resources["PrimaryColor"],
    BarTextColor = Color.White,
};
Navigation = MainPage.Navigation;


protected override void OnStart()
{
    var registrationpage = (Page)ViewFactory.CreatePage(typeof(RegistrationVM));
    MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(registrationpage);
}
```

RegistrationVM :

```
public RegistrationVM()
{            
    Task.Run(async () => await ConnectionAPI());   
}

async Task ConnectionAPI()
{
    try
    {
                applicationContext.Device = mydevice;                                           
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync<LoginVM>(async (vm, p) => await vm.InitializeAsync(this));                           
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(e, "Unhandled exception while loading touch points : {e}", e);
    }
    finally
    {       
    }
}
```

LoginVM :
When the user click on "Login"
PreviousVM = RegistrationVM.

```
async Task Login()
{
    try
    {
        Log.Information("Logging in");                 
        applicationContext.User = employe;
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        await Navigation.RemoveAsync(previousVM);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(e, "Unhandled exception during log in : {e}", e);
    }
    finally
    {       
    }
}
```

I come back to Registration view

Comment: Can you share your code of `ViewFactory`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just pop all modal windows, you can should be able to keep calling PopModalAsync() until Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count is 0, or you get an ArgumentOutofRangeException.

That said, you might want to consider using a different approach here. Most apps that require a login page don't want to have any other pages loaded while it's displayed. In other words, you don't want the user to be able to back out to your main page unless they are logged in, so you don't want anything else on the stack.

To do this, you can replace the Application.Current.MainPage with your login and/or registration page. When login is complete, you replace it with your app's main navigation page.